# what is the Action-Mapping XML file?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller

need to get a few things cleared up. I have been looking for an answer for this one, but I can't seem to find a good answer to my specific questions
I read that

> " Controller Servlet works as a dispatcher transmits all the received
>   HTTP requests to the relevant Actions.

and I have read

> "Use Action-Mapping XML file to execute the action"

can you explain the different and is there a relation between Controller Servlet and Action-Mapping XML ?
and the reation between Controller and Servlet ?
and what happen when user click to button in view does they execute Action-Mapping XML ?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Where are these citations from?

Comment: this is from sap web application architecture

Answer (score 0):

Dispatcher servlet is the [Front Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) which will select the appropriate action to execute. The action mappings in XML or more recently annotation form are used to configure it. This has several advantages, which are discussed in the link.

Comment: can you give me the link and does Dispatcher servlet responsable to select the controller ?

Comment: Click the blue part in my answer, genius.